# Determinant with one parameter, how to deal with this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

> Let $t\in \mathbb R$ be a parameter, and
>   $$|A(t)|=
> \begin{vmatrix}
> a_{11}+t &a_{12}+t &\cdots &a_{1n}+t\\
> a_{21}+t &a_{22}+t &\cdots &a_{2n}+t\\
> \vdots   &\vdots   &       &\vdots\\
> a_{n1}+t &a_{n2}+t &\cdots &a_{nn}+t
> \end{vmatrix}
> $$ 
>   Prove:
>   $$|A(t)|=|A(0)|+\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}A_{ij}$$
>   where $A_{ij}$ denotes the cofactor of $a_{ij}$ within $|A(0)|$.

My attempt:
I have tried the two following ways, but both don't seem to work:
1).Induction. The hypothesis is that it holds for $A_k(t)$ of the size $k\times k$ and I am to show it also holds for $A_{k+1}(t)$. I tried expanding $A_{k+1}(t)$ by the first row or column, but the result was too complicated to deal with, although I did obtain a $|A_{k+1}(0)|$ from it.
2).Another thread was to use 
$$|A_{k+1}(t)|=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &t  &t &\cdots&t \\
0 &a_{11}+t &a_{12}+t &\cdots &a_{1,k+1}+t\\
0 &a_{21}+t &a_{22}+t &\cdots &a_{2,k+1}+t\\
\vdots &\vdots   &\vdots   &       &\vdots\\
0 &a_{k+1,1}+t &a_{k+1,2}+t &\cdots &a_{k+1,k+1}+t
\end{vmatrix}
$$ 
and then substracted the first row from out all the others, I obtained
$$|A_{k+1}(t)|=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &t  &t &\cdots&t \\
-1 &a_{11} &a_{12} &\cdots &a_{1,k+1}\\
-1 &a_{21} &a_{22} &\cdots &a_{2,k+1}\\
\vdots &\vdots   &\vdots   &       &\vdots\\
-1 &a_{k+1,1} &a_{k+1,2} &\cdots &a_{k+1,k+1}
\end{vmatrix}$$
Then I thought I should proceed to expanding the first row or column, in both cases I also obtained a $|A_{k+1}(0)|$, but the rest was just a terrible mess.

I expect that maybe I need some extra tricks to deal with the second term of RHS, i.e., the sum of *all* the cofactors of $a_{ij}$. I know the Laplace expansion, but it doesn't seem to suit this case. Could you help me? Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be the vector with $1$ on each coordinate. Let $A_i$ be column vectors of $A$. Then :

$$det(A)=det(A_1+tv,A_2+tv,...,A_n+tv)$$

Let us set $B_k^0:=A_k$ and $B_k^1:=v$ then expanding $det(A)$ by multilinearity :

$$det(A)=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{E\in\mathcal{P}_i(\{1,...,n\})}t^k.det((B_k^{\chi_E(k)})_{1\leq k\leq n}) $$

But if $i\geq 2$ and $E\in \mathcal{P}_i(\{1,...,n\})$ then for at least two $k$ we have that $B_k^{\chi_E(k)}=v$ then in that case :

$$det((B_k^{\chi_E(k)})_{1\leq k\leq n})=0$$

This means that :

$$det(A)=t^0det(A_1,...,A_n)+t\sum_{r=1}^ndet(A_1,...,A_{r-1},v,A_{r+1},...,A_n)$$

Now (expanding the determinant with respect to the $r$-th column) :

$$det(A_1,...,A_{r-1},v,A_{r+1},...,A_n)=\sum_{j=1}^nA_{j,r}$$

$$det(A)=det(A(0))+t\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_{j,r}$$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't quite know what property  "expanding by multi-linearity " comes from.

Comment: And what does $\chi_E(k)$ denote?

Comment: Yes, it is not as clear as it should be. Do it for $n=3$ : $det(A_1+tv,A_2+tv,A_3+tv)=det(A_1,A_2,A_3)+t(det(v,A_2,A_3)+det(A_1,v,A_3)+det(A_1,A_2,v))+t^2(det(A_1,v,v)+det(v,A_2,v)+det(v,v,A_3))+t^3det(v,v,v)$ then all terms with at least two $v's$ vanish.

Comment: $\chi_E(k)=1$ if $k\in E$ and $0$ if $k\notin E$.

Comment: thanks. Now I seem to follow what you said.

Comment: By the way, does Pi denote permutation or combination?